# How to find the next occurrance of a string in QWebview

Tags: javascript, pyqt

To find a string in a webpage loaded in a QWebView you have two options, either with window.find in javascript or with QWebPage.findText in python.
But how to find the the next occurrance of the string or how can I iterate through a webpage like the find function in FF. For javascript I realized a function but this is surely not state of the art and for certain reasons I'll realize it in python. Thanks
(Sorrry for my English)

Comment: [QWebPage.findText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#findText) already does that.

Comment: Sorry for my question, but I made a big, big, ....... fault. I call 'findText' from javascript, so 'findText' starts searching always from the begin of the page.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you show some example code?

Comment: @ekhumoro I forgot to say the problem is solved. I called 'findText' with a click on a button in the webpage, so 'findText' starts always searching from the top of the webpage (that's a normal behaviour), the next occurrance therefore can't be found. When I place my search button in pyQt than 'findText' works as described in the documentation. Thanks for your help.